# xslt copy element with method = "text"

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to convert an html document to json, so I'm using `<xsl output method="text"/>`.

However, in some places, I want to output an copy of the current element, with some adjustments. Additionally, I want to apply templates to the child elements, rather than copying everything exactly.

If I use the identity transformation with `method="text"`, it only copies the text nodes and ignores everything else.

**Input**

```
<div>test</div>
```

**XSLT**

```
  <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:transform>
```

**Output**

```
test
```

**Desired output**

```
<div>test</div>
```

Is there anyway to output the current element including tags and attributes without setting method to xml?

Comment: XSLT 3 with XPath 3 has a `serialize` function to achieve that.

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Saxon 9.8 and later support the `serialize` function from XPath 3 and earlier versions of Saxon, at least for the commercial editions, have an extension function similar to the XPath 3 `serialize` function.

Comment: I'm using XSLT  3, and the serialize function does exactly what I asked for. Thank you.
I think I asked the wrong question though. In some cases, I want to apply template to one of the child elements to change an attribute value, or to ignore some elements entirely, rather than copy the current element and all of its descendants exactly. Serialize doesn't seem to let you do that.

Comment: Currently I'm using 2 xslt files: one for xml -> xml, and another for xml -> json. I can change attribute values and remove certain elements in the first xslt file, and then use serialize to output those elements as needed as json values in the second file. It would be nicer if there were a way to do this with a single xslt transformation though.

Comment: Put the first step into an `xsl:variable`, then use the variable as the input to the second step.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That did the job. Thank you so much!